# Перенос строки посредством php для корректности JS

Tags: строки, php, javascript

В общем, у меня такая проблема. Вывожу текст, который обрабатывается JS, но если в тексте есть перенос строки, причём ладно перенос на новую строку, его обрабатывает `nl2br();`, но когда перенос на 2 и более строк, то почему-то он уже не работает, а, как известно, лишний перенос в JS - это ошибка, и код перестаёт работать. Как мне убрать лишний перенос?

Вот мой текущий код, который обрабатывает только один перенос:

```
$map_about = @nl2br($map_about); $map_about = preg_replace('/\s+$/m', ' ', $map_about);
```

Comment: @Enterely, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

"Шаблонизировать" JS не лучшая практика, и всегда возникает много проблем. Я бы на вашем месте воспользовался `JSON`:

- На стороне сервера: http://php.ru/manual/function.json-encode.html
- На стороне клиента: http://learn.javascript.ru/json